# Write a function called "get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value"

Tags: python, dictionary

Write a function called "get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value".

Given a dictionary and a key, "get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value" returns a list containing all the elements of the list located at the given key that are equal to ten.

Notes:

If the list is empty, it should return an empty list.

If the list contains no elements that are equal to 10, it should return an empty list.

If the value at the given key is not a list, it should return an empty list.

If the key doesn't exist or its value is None, it should return an empty list.

```
obj1 = {'key': [1000, 10, 50, 10]}
output1 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj1, 'key')
print(output1) # --> [10, 10]
```

```
obj2 = {'key': 10}
output2 = get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj2, 'key')
print(output2) # --> []
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
    newList = []
    for key, value in obj.items():
        if (isinstance(value, (int, float)) and value == 10):
            newList.append(value)
        if (isinstance(value, list) and value == 10):
            newList.append(value)
        if not (isinstance(value, list)):
            return []
        if (isinstance(value, list) and value == None):
            return []
    
  
    return newList
```

This is the error I am getting

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [10, 10]
```

Comment: Is this an assignment problem?

Comment: It is for practice problem for a program I am training to for. @BalajiAmbresh

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
    values = obj.get(key)
    if not isinstance(values, list):
        return []
    return [x for x in values if x == 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)
This might just be what you are looking for:

```
def get_elements_that_equal_10_at_a_value(obj, key):
if not isinstance(obj.get(key), list):
    return[]
return [i for i in obj.get(key,[]) if i == 10]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Is there any way you could please write an expanded version? I am still somewhat new to python and coding, and I have not had much experience with comprehensions. What has been helping me learn comprehensions is to see the expanded code next to the comprehension.